# Is there a conflict between `syntax enable` and custom keywords?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax, keyword

I have the following minimal .vimrc file:

```
" syntax enable
syntax case match
syntax keyword MyTodo TODO PENDING 
syntax keyword MyTodoIP IN PROGRESS 
syntax keyword MyTodoClosed CLOSED COMPLETE DONE
hi MyTodo        ctermfg=yellow
hi MyTodoIP      ctermfg=darkgreen
hi MyTodoClosed  ctermfg=darkgray
```

As is, this works fine (`TODO`, etc are correctly highlighted).
However, **When I uncomment `syntax enable`, my syntax keywords are not highlighted as I have specified.**

I looked at `:help syn-enable` and it says the following:

> The `:syntax enable` command will keep your current color settings.
>   This allows using `:highlight` commands to set your preferred colors
>   before or after using this command.

I also tried using

```
syntax match MyTodoMatch "TODO"
```

with `hi MyTodoWatch` with the same result.

There is [a similar question on stackoverflow from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8423228/2778474) that seems to be having the same problem, but no solution so I'm posting here.

What am I missing here? **How can I use `syntax enable` with custom `keywords`?**

Additionally, with `syntax enable` 'enabled', I can `source ~/.vimrc` after opening vim and the desired syntax *is* applied correctly.

Comment: can't reproduce.  can you provide more information about how you're running vim?  what version etc?

Comment: From `vim --version`: ```VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 19 2019 12:07:03)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-950
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-): ... ``` ... The relevant feature seems to be included: `+syntax`. There's a lot more

Comment: Are you using `syntax enable` somewhere else in your set up (somewhere below `$HOME/.vim`)? If so, this would reset all syntax items, if syntax is already enabled (but not the highlighting).

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation I have, is that there is another `syntax enable` (or `syntax on`) somewhere.

Background: If `syntax enable` is executed and syntax was enabled before, all
syntax items are cleared. See `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim` line 12.  The
documentation only talks about `:highlight`, not `:syntax`.

If you have the directory `$HOME/.vim` with other setup files, rename it to
`$HOME/.vim.off` and test again.

If that doesn't help, you could run:

```
vim -V15verbose.out ...
```

Replace `...` with whatever you use to reproduce the problem. After Vim is started, check that the problem can be reproduced and exit Vim.

This command will write a trace of all commands to the file `verbose.out`. You
can then grep that file for `syntax enable` or `syntax on` to check if there is another invocation.

Note that Vim appends to that file, so you might want to delete it between tries.

Update: You should also check `verbose.log` for `sy clear`, `syn clear` or `syntax clear`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (move .vim to .vim.off) and I still have the same problem. I checked the verbose output as you suggested, and the only instances of `syntax on|enable` that I find (other than the one in my example .vimrc) are in comment blocks in syntax files in MacVim. I'm going to try removing MacVim.

Comment: @John Than I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @John Minor update (last line)